# Metrizable and Hausdorff space.

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

Consider $(\mathbb{Z}, T)$, where $T$ is the topology generated by sets of the form $$A_{m, n}=\{m+nk\ | k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$  for $m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\neq 0$. Then, show that

1. $(\mathbb{Z}, T)$ is Hausdorff.
2. $(\mathbb{Z}, T)$ is meterizable.

For Hausdorff, let $z_1, z_2$ be any two elements of $\mathbb{Z}$. Then, we need to look for two disjoint open sets that act as neighborhoods of $z_1$ and $z_2$. We can construct such open sets. This means $(\mathbb{Z}, T)$ is Hausdorff. But I am not getting how to check (\mathbb{Z}, T)$ is meterizable. Please help.

Comment: One way would be to use Urysohn's metrization theorem. You've prove that is is Hausdorff, it clearly is second countable, then all you need to show that it is regular.

Comment: Also, a link to a blog post given in the above question provides a specific metric that generates this topology:$$d(x, y) = \inf\left\{\frac{1}{n} : n! \mid (x - y) \right\}.$$